# How to remove specific content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this element appearing on page:

```
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Front</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Category 1</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Category 2</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Front</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Category 3</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Front</span>
```

I need to remove every instance of this:

```
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Front</span>
```

There are other categories also listed in the same way and I need that particular category element **(span + text)** to be removed. There is currently no possibility of adding any specific `class` or `id` to the element so it has to be removed in other way.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` and then check `innerHTML`?

Comment: lucky it has a class already ... use the class you've got ... by removed do you mean, removed from the DOM, or simply hidden (display:none)

Answer (score 2):

Use the class name in your selector so you can loop over the elements.

Then, check the contents of each entry, and if a match is found, wrap the current ref in a jQuery object and use `remove`, which will remove it from the DOM.

```
jQuery('span.vc_gitem-post-category-name').each(function() {
  var text = this.innerHTML;
  if (text === 'Front') {
      jQuery(this).remove();
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/vucucipeho/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: should that be `span.vc_gitem-post-category-name` to be 100% accurate to the question :p

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this with javascript as well:

https://jsfiddle.net/dhanrajv/av1twkqs/

```js
var byClassName = document.querySelectorAll('span.vc_gitem-post-category-name');

for(var i=byClassName.length;i--;){
    if(byClassName[i].innerHTML === 'Front') {
        window.document.body.removeChild(byClassName[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Front</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Category 1</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Category 2</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Front</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Category 3</span>
<span class="vc_gitem-post-category-name">Front</span>
```